# Fixed table header in Angular Material Design

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, fixed-header-tables

How to make table sticky header using md-toolbar

I have included thead inside md-toolbar for fixed table header, when i scroll the table content the header is not fixed to top. Below is my code and link to codepen http://codepen.io/apps4any/pen/WQgKMw

```
 <html lang="en" ng-app="demoApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.1/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rawgit.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/master/dist/md-data-table.css">
  </head>
  <body layout="column">
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <div class="md-title">Material Design Data Table</div>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content layout="column" flex>
      <md-card ng-controller="nutritionController">
        <md-data-table-container>
          <table md-data-table class="md-primary" md-row-select="selected" md-progress="deferred">
           <md-toolbar>
            <thead md-order="query.order" md-trigger="onorderchange">
              <tr>
                <th order-by="name" name="Dessert" unit="100g serving"></th>
                <th order-by="type" name="Type"></th>
                <th numeric order-by="calories.value" name="Calories"></th>
                <th numeric unit="g" order-by="fat.value" name="Fat"></th>
                <th numeric unit="g" order-by="carbs.value" name="Carbs"></th>
                <th numeric unit="g" order-by="protein.value" name="Protein"></th>
                <th numeric unit="mg" order-by="sodium.value" name="Sodium"></th>
                <th numeric unit="%" order-by="calcium.value" name="Calcium"></th>
                <th numeric unit="%" order-by="iron.value" name="Iron"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
         </md-toolbar>
       <tbody>
              <tr md-auto-select md-disable-select="dessert.name === 'Jelly bean'" ng-repeat="dessert in desserts.data | orderBy: query.order | limitTo: query.limit: (query.page - 1) * query.limit">
                <td>{{dessert.name}}</td>
                <td>
                  <md-select ng-model="dessert.type" placeholder="Other">
                    <md-option ng-value="type" ng-repeat="type in getTypes()">{{type}}</md-option>
                  </md-select>
                </td>
                <td>{{dessert.calories.value}}</td>
                <td>{{dessert.fat.value | number: 2}}</td>
                <td>{{dessert.carbs.value}}</td>
                <td>{{dessert.protein.value | number: 2}}</td>
                <td>{{dessert.sodium.value}}</td>
                <td show-unit>{{dessert.calcium.value}}</td>
                <td show-unit>{{dessert.iron.value}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </md-data-table-container>

        <md-data-table-pagination md-limit="query.limit" md-page="query.page" md-total="{{desserts.count}}" md-trigger="onpagechange"></md-data-table-pagination>
      </md-card>
    </md-content>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/master/dist/md-data-table.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngMaterial', 'md.data.table'])

.controller('nutritionController', ['$q', '$scope', '$timeout', function ($q, $scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.selected = [];

  $scope.query = {
    order: 'name',
    limit: 15,
    page: 1
  };

  $scope.desserts = {
    "count": 9,
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Frozen yogurt",
        "type": "Ice cream",
        "calories": { "value": 159.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 6.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 24.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 4.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 87.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 14.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 1.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Ice cream sandwich",
        "type": "Ice cream",
        "calories": { "value": 237.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 9.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 37.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 4.3 },
        "sodium": { "value": 129.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 8.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 1.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Eclair",
        "type": "Pastry",
        "calories": { "value":  262.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 16.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 24.0 },
        "protein": { "value":  6.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 337.0 },
        "calcium": { "value":  6.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 7.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Cupcake",
        "type": "Pastry",
        "calories": { "value":  305.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 3.7 },
        "carbs": { "value": 67.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 4.3 },
        "sodium": { "value": 413.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 3.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 8.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Jelly bean",
        "type": "Candy",
        "calories": { "value":  375.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 0.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 94.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 0.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 50.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 0.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 0.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Lollipop",
        "type": "Candy",
        "calories": { "value": 392.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 0.2 },
        "carbs": { "value": 98.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 0.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 38.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 0.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 2.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Honeycomb",
        "type": "Other",
        "calories": { "value": 408.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 3.2 },
        "carbs": { "value": 87.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 6.5 },
        "sodium": { "value": 562.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 0.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 45.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "Donut",
        "type": "Pastry",
        "calories": { "value": 452.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 25.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 51.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 4.9 },
        "sodium": { "value": 326.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 2.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 22.0 }
      }, {
        "name": "KitKat",
        "type": "Candy",
        "calories": { "value": 518.0 },
        "fat": { "value": 26.0 },
        "carbs": { "value": 65.0 },
        "protein": { "value": 7.0 },
        "sodium": { "value": 54.0 },
        "calcium": { "value": 12.0 },
        "iron": { "value": 6.0 }
      }
    ]
  };

  $scope.getTypes = function () {
    return ['Candy', 'Ice cream', 'Other', 'Pastry'];
  };

  $scope.onpagechange = function(page, limit) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function () {
      deferred.resolve();
    }, 2000);

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  $scope.onorderchange = function(order) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function () {
      deferred.resolve();
    }, 2000);

    return deferred.promise;
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The author of md-data-table has another directive available via github that you can use in conjunction with md-data-table to create a fixed header. It's located here: https://github.com/daniel-nagy/fixed-table-header

I am using it in a couple of places successfully.